# Redirect After Login Error

Tags: redirect, login

I have three login pages set up for different languages (it's how we had to set our site up for a whole host of reasons around our site). We've got wp-login.php, wp-login_cn.php (Chinese) and wp-login_jp.php (Japanese).

Everything works fine except for when there is a login error. For example, if the user enters the wrong password, they are redirected to 'wp-login.php' regardless of which login page they are on. I'm pretty sure it is in the backend/core files of WordPress somewhere because I don't see that redirect anymore in the actual PHP code in the wp-login.php file.

Does anyone know how I can keep the page from redirecting to the wp-login.php when it's on the other language pages? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a hook for this: wp_login_failed.

Comment: Ok great, will try this now and then check back with you if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick, it's still redirecting back to the English page. I'll look at the code a little more deeply and see if I can work something around it...

Comment: It's strange because I'm writing out the 'referrer' variable to the console to check and see if it's correct and it's picking up the correct 'referrer' value but it still directs back to the English page...I'll keep looking into, this was a good thing to start with.